# ECLIPSE - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while working with JNI

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

Hi everybody: I'm making practice with JNI on my Windows 7.
My goal is to print at the Eclipse console a "Hello world" message using C's API.

I keep getting

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStuff.HelloJNI.sayHello()V
    at nativeStuff.HelloJNI.sayHello(Native Method)
    at main.Init.main(Init.java:17)`

On my project's `Properties` -> `Libraries` -> `jre8` -> `Native Library Location` -> `Edit` -> `Workspace` I set `nativeStuff` as selected folder, since the library `hello.dll` is in there, but I keep getting the same error about `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Here's the source tree:

```
src(folder):
    main(package):
        Init.java
    nativeStuff(package):
        HelloJNI.java
        hello.dll
        HelloJNI.c
        nativeStuff_HelloJNI.h
```

Init.java:

```
public class Init {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin");
        new HelloJNI().sayHello(); // from the exception above
    }
}
```

HelloJNI.java:

```
public class HelloJNI {
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("hello");
        } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError u) { // always from the exception above
            u.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SecurityException s) {
            s.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public native void sayHello();  
}
```

nativeStuff_HelloJNI.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class nativeStuff_HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_nativeStuff_HelloJNI
#define _Included_nativeStuff_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     nativeStuff_HelloJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nativeStuff_HelloJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and HelloJNI.c:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nativeStuff_HelloJNI.h"

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

**[Edit]**: these are the commands I typed to get the files...

```
javac HelloJNI.java
javah -jni nativeStuff.HelloJNI
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
```

Comment: I believe `hello.c` is the compilation result of `HelloJNI.c` right ? Don't you forgot to add it to your classpath ?

Comment: What `hello.c` are you talking about?
Wait, let me edit the commands I typed to get all those files

Comment: And could you post the command you use to launch the java program ?

Comment: I'm working on Eclipse, so I just click on `run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.loadLibrary` is intended for system libraries, which are usually located in a jre subfolder. If you want to load a local library like in your example, use instead :

```
System.load("/path/to/your/lib.ext")
```

See [jre javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String))

---

Finally, the error was : name of function had to be qualified : `Java_nativeCode_HelloJNI_sayHello` instead of `Java_HelloJNI_sayHello` inside .h and .c

Comment: The actual loading code could be `System.load(Init.class.getResource("./hello.dll").getFile())`

Comment: I did as you suggested: 
`System.load(Init.class.getResource("./hello.dll").getFile())`
returns
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at main.Init.main(Init.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nativeStuff.HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:10)`
i.e. the line you suggested

Comment: This obviously happens because the resource isn't found, meaning either that `hello.dll` isn't on the classpath, either because the path i used isn't correct (which i doubt).

Comment: How can I add an extern .dll library in my project?
I added hello.dll in the Java Build Path, Libraries, etc as written above: is not this enough?

Comment: Yes, having the library on the classpath is enough for `Class.getResource()` to find it, so the exception shouldn't occur. Try writting with more detail, then put a breakpoint and see where exactly the exception occurs.

Comment: Oh sorry, i think i've made a mistake, try instead : `System.load(HelloJNI.class.getResource("./hello.dll").getFile())`, the first cannot work since `Init` and `hello.dll` aren't in the same folder.

Comment: Maybe some permission issue. Don't know how to help more. If your send me your project i can have a look.

Comment: I don't understand a couple of things:

1) in the exception, does the path which can't be loaded `/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/backup%20andrea/windows/workspace/MyElance/bin/nativeCode/hello.dll` need to start with that `/`? Maybe a parsing error?

2) `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeCode.HelloJNI.sayHello()V`: what the hell is that `V` at the end of the line?

3) the folder that contains Eclipse's workspace has a blankspace in its name (`backup andrea`, seen as `backup%20andrea`): would this be a problem?

Comment: 1) The path starting with '/' is strange indeed, but i believe its an internal representation of java, each drive being considered as a folder of the root of the system. 2) The 'V' indicates the return type (void). 3) Blank spaces often produce problem, you might try putting your file in a file located as near of the root as possible, without any whitespace in the path, and no folder name exceeding 8 chars to verify the problem isn't coming from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59197/discussion-between-elmazzun-and-antoine-marques).

Comment: Correction: from Java 8, `System.loadLibrary` is intended to load a native library, not necessarily a system library. As per javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-):
"Loads the native library specified by the libname argument."